# I want to coordinate two NSMutableDictionary(s)

Tags: objective-c

```
dictProductList =    (
        {
        "product_capacity" = "20.00";
        "product_code" = ITEM001;
        "product_description" = test;
        "product_id" = 1;
        "product_name" = "Water Bottle";
        "product_price" = "25.00";
        "product_unit" = LTR;
    }
)
```

and another one is

```
 NSMutableDictionary *firstOne = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [firstOne setObject:@"5" forKey:@"product_quantity"];
```

While I am try to add this two mutable dictionary I got error. Am using this below method.

```
[dictProductList addEntriesFromDictionary:firstOne];
```

The error message is

```
-[__NSArrayM addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166d87f0
```

Comment: Please invest more time into your questions, like proper formatting. Nobody wants to read such a mess (and since this is your 8th question, you don't have an excuse any more). If you improve the quality of your questions, you're more likely to get good answer (or to actually get _any_ answer at all).

Comment: is it your log from debug console?

Comment: Also, the question is very confusing. I have no idea what you actually want. An example might help. (I know you won't do it, but anyways: **Please _edit_ your question to provide the additional info; don't add them as comments.**)

Comment: yup this is my console

Comment: Can you add code which is responsible for printing it out?

Comment: Show the code that creates `dictProductList`. It looks like it is an array with one dictionary in it.

Comment: There is no `NSMUTABLEDICTIONARY`, perhaps you mean `NSMutableDictionary`. ;-)

Comment: @zaph - easier to fix than complain :)

Comment: It is a learning thing.

Comment: Thanks brothers for your support finally i got solution. Sorry for my bad English..

Answer (score 0):

Show the code that creates `dictProductList`. It looks like it is an array with one dictionary in it.

The error: " -[__NSArrayM addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x166d87f0"
says that the message `addEntriesFromDictionary` was sent to an `NSMutableArray`.

It in fact `dictProductList` is an `NSMutableArray` the correct code would be:

```
[dictProductList addObject:firstOne];
```

In Objective-C the error message are usually helpful and it is worthwhile taking the time to understand them. In this case it say the message was sent to an `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableArray` has no message `addEntriesFromDictionary`. So either the object is incorrect or the message is incorrect.

Comment: Finally i got solution.. Thanks.